# using mysql LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a duplicate username checker and I am thinking this is probably the way to do it correct me if im wrong. Basically I want the username the user input to be stored in a variable called `userName` and then use that variable to check and see if there are any `LIKE` rows in the database and if so return a count of 1 or more to a variable named `$count`  I would then have an `IF ELSE` statement that would either yell at the user or let them continue. I have run into a problem using the `LIKE` statement. I think my syntax could be wrong since I have been trying several different methods but still no luck.

### Main Code

```
<?php

require 'DB.php';
$userName = "tes";
echo $userName;
try{
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name` LIKE "% . ":userName" . "');
$stmt->bindValue(':userName', $userName);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
return $count;
echo $count;

} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();

    }


?>
```

Comment: Why do you use `LIKE`and wildcards when looking for possible duplicates? Looking for exact matches (using `=`) would be more natural.

Comment: If i used the `=` operator would that be case insensitive I read the `LIKE` operator is case insensitive I dont want the user to be able to make an account if the username is `Test` and there is already one in the database `test`

Comment: You can also use `UPPER` (or `LOWER`) to convert everything in uppercase and therefore lose the need for case sensitivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're trying to do string concatenation in MySQL using invalid syntax.  Try this:

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name` LIKE CONCAT("%",:userName)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use = instead of LIKE. The SQL syntax in itself isn't case-sensitive. I think you might be able to set up your database so that certain tables are case sensitive but I know for a fact through usage that no tables in my own MySQL database are. If you're unsure it's easy to try, just run a select with a username you know is in there but write it with different casing.

Just do a select WHERE 'user_name'=$entered_username, if you get one or more don't add the new user, if not go ahead. You could of course mark the user_field as unique, that way you'd know for sure you won't have duplicates, might be something worth looking at.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use this select:

("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name` LIKE "% . "'".$userName."'");

Comment: This is a natural SQL Injection exploit.

Comment: @MichaelRice The code that I am trying to implement in the question is safe from SQL Injection correct? I was told using PDO prepared statements is the best method to safeguard against it.

Comment: Yes, you're good with PDO if you use it properly. E.g. using the bind functions.